# Input Control with Tagging Support

Tags: sapui5

Is there a control which supports tagging in SAP UI5? Something like *[Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)* which turns your tag words into a button like widget, similar to what we see when we add tags here at Stack Overflow.

I want to allow the users to add tags to their posts. Please point me to the control if it exits. If not, how can I use *Tag-it* in my code?

[image]

Comment: Use either `sap.m.MultiInput` or `sap.m.MultiComboBox`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50136618/5846045

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sap.m.Tokenizer` which can hold one or more `sap.m.Token`'s

See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Tokenizer/samples

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a new field to the post which is called "tags" and allow the user to add words there. If you want to search for tags just search including that field. Just a suggestion if you can't find an actual widget.

Answer (score 0):

> Something like [*Tag-it*](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) which turns your tag words into a button like widget, similar to what we see when we add tags here at Stack Overflow.

I guess what you're looking for is [`sap.m.MultiInput`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MultiInput) which behaves like the *Tags* input field on Stack Overflow:

[image: UI5 adding tags with sap.m.MultiInput]

### Implementation

- The control has an aggregation named `<tokens>` to which *n*-[`sap.m.Token`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Token) can be added.
- It also provides the [API `addValidator`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiInput/methods/addValidator) which awaits a function to validate user input before creating a new Token. The function is executed when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, selects a value from the suggestions drop-down, or when the focus leaves the field.
- When the new token was about to be added but the same token was already there, the new token won't be added.

### Demo

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/layout/form/SimpleForm",
  "sap/m/Label",
  "sap/m/MultiInput",
  "sap/m/Token",
], (SimpleForm, Label, MultiInput, Token) => {
  const multiInput = new MultiInput().setShowValueHelp(false);
  multiInput.addValidator(args => new Token({
    key: args.text.trim(),
    text: args.text.trim(),
  }));
  new SimpleForm({
    title: "sap.m.MultiInput",
    content: [
      new Label().setText("Tags"),
      multiInput,
    ],
    layout: "ResponsiveGridLayout",
    editable: true,
  }).placeAt("content");
}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="true"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

<sup>[API reference: `sap.m.MultiInput`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiInput/)</sup>

---

## Alternative

As an alternative control, which might be more appropriate depending on the project, a MultiComboBox could be used.

[image]

<sup>[API reference: `sap.m.MultiComboBox`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiComboBox)</sup>